# Accessing localhost on Android devices in different network, company server is not public

Tags: android, cordova

I am using cordova in visual studio for app development. I need to test app on other devices like Android. Also debug.

But i am not able to access my localhost on Android or any other device. Problems are:
1. Development servers are in different country and are not public.
2. VPN access is not allowed on Android device due to company policy
3. Can not connect Android device to same company wifi due to company policies

I searched and found VirtualBox and some other solutions. But haven't found any post which address this kind of issue.

Sorry if this question is duplicated and if it is then please redirect me to the solution.

It is a big impediment for my team, is there any way to solve this issue as ?

Comment: Sorry but the question is confusing, can elaborate this. `Accessing localhost on Android devices in different network`.

Answer (score 0):

use a computer which can access your localhost build hot spots